# Демаршалинг XML (JAXB)

Tags: java

Добрый вечер, подскажите пож как распарсить XML с помощью JAXB.

Исходный XML:

```
<exchangerates>
<row>
  <exchangerate ccy="UAH" base_ccy="RUR" buy="0.00" sale="0.00"/>
</row>
<row>
  <exchangerate ccy="EUR" base_ccy="RUR" buy="0.00" sale="0.00"/>
</row>
<row>
  <exchangerate ccy="USD" base_ccy="RUR" buy="0.00" sale="0.00"/>
</row>
</exchangerates>
```

Так делаю класс-сущность для XML

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType
    @XmlRootElement(name = "exchangerates")
    public class PbXmlEntity {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "row")
@XmlElement(name = "exchangerate")
    public List<PbXmlEntity> row;

     @XmlAttribute (name = "ccy")
     private String ccy;
         public String getCcy() {
    return ccy;
}

public void setCcy(String ccy) {
    this.ccy = ccy;
}

     @XmlAttribute 
     private String base_ccy;
             public String getBase_ccy() {
        return base_ccy;
    }

    public void setBase_ccy(String base_ccy) {
        this.base_ccy = base_ccy;
    }

     @XmlAttribute (name = "buy")
     private double buy;
             public double getBuy() {
        return buy;
    }

    public void setBuy(double buy) {
        this.buy = buy;
    }

     @XmlAttribute (name = "sale")
     private double sale;
             public double getSale() {
        return sale;
    }

    public void setSale(double sale) {
        this.sale = sale;
    }
```

}

Листинг класса-обработчика :

```
    public class PbJaxb {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File xmlFile = new File("in.xml");
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PbXmlEntity.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        PbXmlEntity unmarshal = (PbXmlEntity) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

          System.out.println("ccy:"+unmarshal.getCcy());
          System.out.println("Base_ccy:"+unmarshal.getBase_ccy());
          System.out.println("buy:"+unmarshal.getBuy());
          System.out.println("sale:"+unmarshal.getSale());

    } catch (JAXBException ex) {}

}
```

}

В итоге получаю :

ccy:null
Base_ccy:null
buy:0.0
sale:0.0

как правильно добраться до атрибутов тега в этом случае?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сущность у вас никуда не годится.

1. Во-первых, она вложена сама в себя. То есть `exchangerates` превратится в корневой бин `PbXmlEntity`, `row/exchangerate` по вашей задумке лягут в `List<PbXmlEntity>`. При этом в коде вы обращаетесь к полям корневого бина (`unmarshal.getCcy()`), которых в исходных данных нет. Но это все в принципе не получится, потому что:
2. Во-вторых, JAXB не умеет "из-коробки" на аннотациях заворачивать поле в два тега.
3. В-третьих, аннотация `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "row")` говорит, что сейчас будет коллекция бинов внутри тега `<row></row>`, а не каждый бин завернут в свой отдельный `<row>` (см. пункт 2).

В самом лобовом варианте это можно описать так (для компактности без геттеров-сеттеров):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(name = "exchangerates")
public class ExchangeRates {
    @XmlElement(name = "row")
    public List<Row> rows;

    @XmlType
    public static class Row {
        @XmlElement(name = "exchangerate")
        public ExchangeRate rate;
    }

    @XmlType
    public static class ExchangeRate {
        @XmlAttribute(name = "ccy")
        public String ccy;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "base_ccy")
        public String base_ccy;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "buy")
        public double buy;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "sale")
        public double sale;
    }
}
```

Тогда мы сможем вывести все это дело, например в цикле:

```
for (ExchangeRates.Row row : unmarshal.rows) {
    System.out.println(row.rate.ccy);
    System.out.println(row.rate.base_ccy);
    System.out.println(row.rate.buy);
    System.out.println(row.rate.sale);
}
```

Конечно, тут наблюдается неприятный момент в виде промежуточной сущности `Row`, которая не несет смысловой нагрузки. Но от нее можно избавиться при помощи адаптера.

Для начала напишем адаптер, который умеет "распаковывать" `ExchangeRate` из `Row` и "запаковывать" обратно:

```
public class RowAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Row, ExchangeRate> {

    @Override
    public ExchangeRate unmarshal(Row v) throws Exception {
        return v.rate;
    }

    @Override
    public Row marshal(ExchangeRate v) throws Exception {
        Row row = new Row();
        row.rate = v;
        return row;
    }
}
```

Теперь заменим в классе `ExchangeRates` список `List<Row>` на `List<ExchangeRate>` и укажем, что хотим использовать наш адаптер:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
@XmlRootElement(name = "exchangerates")
public class ExchangeRates {
    @XmlElement(name = "row")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RowAdapter.class)
    public List<ExchangeRate> rates;
}
```

Все! Теперь JAXB сам будет заниматься распаковкой промежуточного слоя, а мы можем обращаться к экземплярам `ExchangeRate` в списке напрямую:

```
    for (ExchangeRates.ExchangeRate rate: unmarshal.rows) {
        System.out.println(rate.ccy);
        System.out.println(rate.base_ccy);
        System.out.println(rate.buy);
        System.out.println(rate.sale);
    }
```

---

PS. Рекомендую сразу привыкать к хорошему, отказаться от стандартной JavaSE реализации JAXB и пользоваться XStream. Все те же аннотации, но гораздо лучше в производительности и удобнее в конфигурации. Плюс, там можно было бы вовсе отказаться от класса `Row`, написав свой сериализатор/десериализатор (получится на десять строк больше, но не будет лишнего класса).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все по делу и понятно!